# Orthogonality relations of Hermite polynomials

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, special-functions

The Hermite polynomials are orthogonal.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_m(x) H_n(x) e^{-x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{ \pi} 2^n n! \delta_{nm}
$$

Does Mathematica not use this relationship? Because running

```
Integrate[(HermiteH[5, x]*HermiteH[5, x])E^(-x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]//Timing
```

took almost 4 seconds, and when n = m = 10, Mathematica fails completely:

[image]

Is it possible to instruct it to refer to this relationship somehow to simplify computation?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using.  Using 10.1 it takes less than a second to calculate `n=m=10`.

Comment: I'm using 10.0. I don't suppose it's some kind of a new feature in 10.1?

Comment: @chuy I see the same as you in version 8.

Comment: i just got home and tried it again and I did get an answer for n=m=5 in 0.1s, n=m=7 in 1.35s, but n=m=8 and higher fails to compute still...

Comment: Same as chuy with 10.0. You might want to consider `Integrate[(HermiteH[10., x]*HermiteH[10, x])E^(-x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]//Timing` (`10.` instead of `10`). But of course you're not going to get the exact value.

Comment: @anderstood, interesting... Why does this work and why doesn't it give the exact value? And I'm still wondering why Mathematica just doesn't go straight to RHS of that equation for n=m.

Comment: I have noticed that in general, *Mathematica* is unaware of the orthogonality relations of its built-in orthogonal polynomials. Why this is so, I do not know…

Comment: fair enough :] i guess i'll just have to throw in an if statement to help it out ...

Comment: @Solarmew: That's because when you use floating numbers, Mathematica does not try to solve it analytically but only numerically. Try `Sqrt[2]` and `Sqrt[2.]`. However, I think `Integrate`switches to `NIntegrate` when it cannot solve. I am absolutely not sure, but maybe Mathematica does not implement this because orthogonality depends on the scalar product... But that's probably stupid.

Comment: `Integrate[(LaguerreL[5, a, x]*LaguerreL[5, a, x]) x^a E^(-x), {x, 0, 
   Infinity}] // Timing` nicely gives `{7.16045,ConditionalExpression[1/120 Gamma[6+a],Re[a]>-1]}` in version 10.1. But the HermiteH seems not to have a build-in orthogonality relation.

Comment: Can't believe they still haven't fixed this issue (version 11.3). Not that many classic orthogonal polynomials there, could have made sure Integrate works properly in this case