# Integral involving orthogonal functions (quantum harmonic oscillator eigenstates)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I have a question about the capabilities of the `Integrate` command for general parameters.

We know that there is a system of functions:

```
\[CurlyPhi][n_, x_] = 
  HermiteH[n, x]/Sqrt[2^n*n!*Sqrt[\[Pi]]]*Exp[-0.5 x^2];
```

and we know that for nonnegative integer `n` parameters, these functions are orthonormal in the usual sense of integration. However the following integral:

```
Integrate[\[CurlyPhi][a, x]*\[CurlyPhi][b, 
   x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Integers, a >= 0, b \[Element] Integers,
    b >= 0} ]
```

supposedly does not converge (error `Integrate::idiv`). The correct result should be a Kronecker-delta function.

Have I made a coding error in the assumptions, or should some other command than `Integrate` be used?

Comment: The closest I've ever got to a solution was to do a finite table: `Table[Integrate[φ[a, x]*φ[b, x], {x, -∞, ∞}], {a, 0, 6}, {b, 0, 6}]`. By the way it's better to define your function with exact numbers, not machine-precision numbers like `-0.5`: use `φ[n_, x_] = HermiteH[n, x]/Sqrt[2^n*n!*Sqrt[π]]*Exp[-x^2/2]`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186935/how-to-check-whether-laguerre-polynomials-are-orthogonal, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83552/orthogonality-relations-of-hermite-polynomials

Answer (score 1):

What do mean by "not converge"? MMA simply gives the input back because a and b have no value. MMA can not evaluate the integral symbolically. For pos. integer a and b  it will evaluate. If you need symbolic evaluation, you can teach MMA by e.g.:

```
φ[n_ /; NumericQ, x_] = 
  HermiteH[n, x]/Sqrt[2^n*n!*Sqrt[π]]*Exp[-0.5 x^2];
Unprotect[Integrate];
 Integrate[φ[n1_, x]*φ[n2_, 
      x], {x, -∞, ∞}] /; (n1 =!= n2 ) = 0;
 Integrate[φ[n1_, x]*φ[n1_, 
     x], {x, -∞, ∞}] = 1;
Protect[Integrate];
```

Then the following evaluate as you request:

```
Integrate[φ[n1, x]*φ[n2, x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
Integrate[φ[n1, x]*φ[n1, x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

By the way, "convergence" has quite another meaning, look it up.

Comment: The OP's code produces this for me: "Integrate::idiv: Integral of (2^(1/2 (-a-b)) E^-x^2 HermiteH[a,x] HermiteH[b,x])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[a! b!]) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}."

Comment: I checked it again, I get 0 and 1. Try with a new kernel.  I have MMA 12.1.0

Comment: I have 12.1.1.  Maybe there's a version difference. I don't think the integral converges if `a`, `b` are nonintegers, so perhaps the `Integers` assumption is dropped. Of course the integral converges when `a` and `b` are integers, but `Integrate[]` reports divergence. (Note that I'm not talking about your re-definition of `Integrate`, just the original code with the standard `Integrate`.)

Comment: I assumed n>=0 for the harmonic oscillator. I do not know where hermite polynomials with non integer index pop up.

Comment: They pop up from the defining ODE.  I just mean that `Integrate` takes this into account when it reports the integral does not converge.  I think that's what causes the error that `Integrate` reports, which is why the OP thought the integral "supposedly does not converge." I'm responding to the first sentence in your answer with a suggestion why the OP says "not converge."  (I haven't tried your code yet, because I don't want to mess with `Integrate` and then have to kill my kernel.)

Comment: @Michael E2 Hi, you must be a mathematician, considering your answer: "They pop up from the defining ODE". Sure, but I am more concerned about physics. If in version 12.1.1 an error message pops up and in 12.1.0 the input is simply returned, I think you should write an report to support@worlfram.com

Comment: I get a "does not converge" in V12.1.0: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c1rs.png -- You must be doing something different, which I suspected because I don't think there's any way that you could get 0 and 1 with this integral.  I changed the `0.5` to `1/2`, but one shouldn't use approximate numbers in an exact solver, and with `0.5` it ran for many minutes before I killed it.

Comment: You are right. With a new start of MMA I now also get the convergence message. I do not know what was different before. However, the added definitions for "Integrate" works.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to any Schrödinger eigenvalue problem with boundary value of the current operator over the boundary equal to zero and discrete discrete spectrum rests on the fact, that the general solution is not square integrable.

For the general algebraic eigenvalues, the solution, starting regularly at $x=0$, explodes exponentially on one of the  boundary points. At the eigenvalue it changes its sign from $\pm \infty \to \mp \infty$.

The general solution of the oscillator problem is

```
    DSolve[(-1/2 D[#, x, x] + 1/2 x^2 # == (n + 1/2) # &)
      [E^(-x^2/2) g[x]], g[x], x]

    {{g[x] ->  C[1] HermiteH[n, x] + 
               C[2] Hypergeometric1F1[-(n/2), 1/2, x^2]}}
```

These functions ar special cases of $_1F_1$ and difficult to handle for integer parameters. But $C[2]\to 0,  n\in N_+$ is the classical solution on $\mathbb R$  with $\partial^{n}\psi(\pm \infty)=0 \implies j(\pm \infty)=0$

The general solutions with no measure factor imposed, are parabolic cylinder functions

```
     DSolve[(-1/2 D[ #, x, x] + 1/2 x^2 # == (n + 1/2) # &)[g[x]], g[x], x]

      {{g[x] -> C[2] ParabolicCylinderD[-1 - n, I Sqrt[2] x] + 
                C[1] ParabolicCylinderD[n, Sqrt[2] x]}}
```

Both subspaces are identical with the $e^{\pm x^2/2} H[n,x]$, decaying on one side and exploding  on the other side. All $L^2$-integrals will be considered non existent for general parameters.

Demo, Log scale on x range

```
 Manipulate[
    Plot[ParabolicCylinderD[n, Sqrt[2] Sinh[x]], {x, -3, 3}], 
  {{n, 3.998}, 3.5, 5.5}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Eigenfunctions of oscillator problem]

Near to an integer eigenvalue there is a minimum near zero. Finding the eigenvalue means shifting the turning point to $\infty$. As a mechanical problem it amounts to threading the needle at infinity with an elastic rod by control of the zero point of the elastic restoring force $-x \psi$, small at the origin, stiff for large x. This is an alternative aspect of the famous index theorems for positive differential operators on manifolds with boundaries, that rest on the diffusion processes of random paths.